# ccls installed in neovim but never works properly

Tags: c++, installation, neovim

Neovim shows warnings and errors that shouldn't appear. Specifically it seems like it works with older versions of C++(like C++98 or C++03):

- No member named 'make_unique' in namespace 'std' (make_unique definitely exists)
- Or, when I try to initialise a variable using braces (like int i{}) it never accepts it and throws errors

This is my .ccls file:

```
clang
%cpp -std=c++2a
%h x
%h c++-header
```

This is my coc-settings.json file:

```
{
"languageserver": {
  "ccls": {
    "command": "ccls",
    "filetypes": ["c", "cc", "cpp", "c++", "objc", "objcpp"],
    "rootPatterns": [".ccls", "compile_commands.json", ".git/", ".hg/", ".vim/"],
    "initializationOptions": {
        "cache": {
          "directory": "/tmp/ccls"
        }
      }
  }
}
}
```

This is my compile_commands.json file:

```
[

    {
        "command": "clang++",
        "arguments": ["-std=c++17", "-Wall", "-I./", "${file}"],
        "directory": "${fileDirname}",
        "file": "${file}",
        "output": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
    }

]
```

The version of clang++ is 13.0.0

And this is my init.vim file:

```
:set number
:set relativenumber
:set autoindent
:set tabstop=4
:set shiftwidth=4
:set smarttab
:set softtabstop=4
:set mouse=a

call plug#begin()

Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'http://github.com/tpope/vim-surround' " Surrounding ysw)
Plug 'https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree' " NerdTree
Plug 'https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary' " For Commenting gcc & gc
Plug 'https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline' " Status bar
"Plug 'https://github.com/lifepillar/pgsql.vim' " PSQL Pluging needs :SQLSetType pgsql.vim
"Plug 'https://github.com/ap/vim-css-color' " CSS Color Preview
Plug 'https://github.com/rafi/awesome-vim-colorschemes' " Retro Scheme
Plug 'https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim', {'do': { -> coc#util#install()}}  " Auto Completion
"Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'tag': '*', 'do': 'yarn install'}
Plug 'https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons' " Developer Icons
Plug 'https://github.com/tc50cal/vim-terminal' " Vim Terminal
Plug 'https://github.com/preservim/tagbar' " Tagbar for code navigation
Plug 'https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors' " CTRL + N for multiple cursors

call plug#end()

set encoding=UTF-8

nnoremap <C-f> :NERDTreeFocus<CR>
nnoremap <C-n> :NERDTree<CR>
nnoremap <C-t> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <C-l> :call CocActionAsync('jumpDefinition')<CR>

nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>

:set completeopt-=preview " For No Previews
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

:colorscheme Molokai

let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable="+"
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible="~"

" --- Just Some Notes ---
" :PlugClean :PlugInstall :UpdateRemotePlugins
"
" :CocInstall coc-python
" :CocInstall coc-clangd
" :CocInstall coc-snippets
" :CocCommand snippets.edit... FOR EACH FILE TYPE
"
" if hidden is not set, TextEdit might fail.
set hidden

" Some servers have issues with backup files, see #649
set nobackup
set nowritebackup

" Better display for messages
set cmdheight=2

" You will have bad experience for diagnostic messages when it's default 4000.
set updatetime=300

" don't give |ins-completion-menu| messages.
set shortmess+=c

" always show signcolumns
set signcolumn=yes

" Use tab for trigger completion with characters ahead and navigate.
" Use command ':verbose imap <tab>' to make sure tab is not mapped by other plugin.
inoremap <silent><expr> <TAB>
      \ pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" :
      \ <SID>check_back_space() ? "\<TAB>" :
      \ coc#refresh()
inoremap <expr><S-TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<C-h>"

function! s:check_back_space() abort
  let col = col('.') - 1
  return !col || getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '\s'
endfunction

" Use <c-space> to trigger completion.
inoremap <silent><expr> <c-space> coc#refresh()

" Use <cr> to confirm completion, `<C-g>u` means break undo chain at current position.
" Coc only does snippet and additional edit on confirm.
inoremap <expr> <cr> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<C-g>u\<CR>"

" Use `[c` and `]c` to navigate diagnostics
nmap <silent> [c <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-prev)
nmap <silent> ]c <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-next)

" Remap keys for gotos
nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
nmap <silent> gy <Plug>(coc-type-definition)
nmap <silent> gi <Plug>(coc-implementation)
nmap <silent> gr <Plug>(coc-references)

" Use K to show documentation in preview window
nnoremap <silent> K :call <SID>show_documentation()<CR>

function! s:show_documentation()
  if (index(['vim','help'], &filetype) >= 0)
    execute 'h '.expand('<cword>')
  else
    call CocAction('doHover')
  endif
endfunction

" Highlight symbol under cursor on CursorHold
autocmd CursorHold * silent call CocActionAsync('highlight')

" Remap for rename current word
nmap <leader>rn <Plug>(coc-rename)

" Remap for format selected region
xmap <leader>f  <Plug>(coc-format-selected)
nmap <leader>f  <Plug>(coc-format-selected)

augroup mygroup
  autocmd!
  " Setup formatexpr specified filetype(s).
  autocmd FileType typescript,json setl formatexpr=CocAction('formatSelected')
  " Update signature help on jump placeholder
  autocmd User CocJumpPlaceholder call CocActionAsync('showSignatureHelp')
augroup end

" Remap for do codeAction of selected region, ex: `<leader>aap` for current paragraph
xmap <leader>a  <Plug>(coc-codeaction-selected)
nmap <leader>a  <Plug>(coc-codeaction-selected)

" Remap for do codeAction of current line
nmap <leader>ac  <Plug>(coc-codeaction)
" Fix autofix problem of current line
nmap <leader>qf  <Plug>(coc-fix-current)

" Use <tab> for select selections ranges, needs server support, like: coc-tsserver, coc-python
nmap <silent> <TAB> <Plug>(coc-range-select)
xmap <silent> <TAB> <Plug>(coc-range-select)
xmap <silent> <S-TAB> <Plug>(coc-range-select-backword)

" Use `:Format` to format current buffer
command! -nargs=0 Format :call CocAction('format')

" Use `:Fold` to fold current buffer
command! -nargs=? Fold :call     CocAction('fold', <f-args>)

" use `:OR` for organize import of current buffer
command! -nargs=0 OR   :call     CocAction('runCommand', 'editor.action.organizeImport')

" Add status line support, for integration with other plugin, checkout `:h coc-status`
set statusline^=%{coc#status()}%{get(b:,'coc_current_function','')}

" Using CocList
" Show all diagnostics
nnoremap <silent> <space>a  :<C-u>CocList diagnostics<cr>
" Manage extensions
nnoremap <silent> <space>e  :<C-u>CocList extensions<cr>
" Show commands
nnoremap <silent> <space>c  :<C-u>CocList commands<cr>
" Find symbol of current document
nnoremap <silent> <space>o  :<C-u>CocList outline<cr>
" Search workspace symbols
nnoremap <silent> <space>s  :<C-u>CocList -I symbols<cr>
" Do default action for next item.
nnoremap <silent> <space>j  :<C-u>CocNext<CR>
" Do default action for previous item.
nnoremap <silent> <space>k  :<C-u>CocPrev<CR>
" Resume latest coc list
nnoremap <silent> <space>p  :<C-u>CocListResume<CR>

" air-line
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

" airline symbols
"let g:airline_left_sep = ''
"let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
"let g:airline_right_sep = ''
"let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
"let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
"let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
"let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ''

inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm() : "<Tab>
```

What am I doing wrong???
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `compile_commands.json` seems odd. This is what I do to make neovim index my .cpp file.

- Create a `CMakeLists.txt` that have this line: `set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)`
- Build my project with `cmake`, then you should have a `compile_commands.json` in your build directory
- Use symlink to create a `compile_commands.json` file which link to the real `compile_commands.json` file (the symlink file should be placed at the same place as `CMakeLists.txt` file)
- Open `nvim` at the same place at `compile_commands.json` symlink file

This is an example of my `compile_commands.json` file:

```
[
{
  "directory": "/Users/dla/workspace/minhduc/Coding-Exercises/Divers/Test/C++/build",
  "command": "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++  -I/Users/dla/workspace/minhduc/Coding-Exercises/Divers/Test/C++/include -I/Users/dla/workspace/minhduc/Coding-Exercises/Divers/Test/C++/../../../Common/C++ -isystem /Users/dla/workspace/minhduc/Coding-Exercises/Divers/Test/C++/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include -isystem /Users/dla/workspace/minhduc/Coding-Exercises/Divers/Test/C++/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk -Wno-unused-result -Werror=reorder -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/main-test.dir/main_test.cpp.o -c /Users/dla/workspace/minhduc/Coding-Exercises/Divers/Test/C++/main_test.cpp",
  "file": "/Users/dla/workspace/minhduc/Coding-Exercises/Divers/Test/C++/main_test.cpp"
},
{
  "directory": "/Users/dla/workspace/minhduc/Coding-Exercises/Divers/Test/C++/build",
  "command": "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++  -I/Users/dla/workspace/minhduc/Coding-Exercises/Divers/Test/C++/include -I/Users/dla/workspace/minhduc/Coding-Exercises/Divers/Test/C++/../../../Common/C++  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk -Wno-unused-result -Werror=reorder -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/dla/workspace/minhduc/Coding-Exercises/Divers/Test/C++/main.cpp",
  "file": "/Users/dla/workspace/minhduc/Coding-Exercises/Divers/Test/C++/main.cpp"
}
]
```